# Azure AD Connect with Office365

Tags: wordpress, azure, active-directory, single-sign-on

I'm trying to install an Office365 authentication on my website running Wordpress.I have a few questions :

- My server runs on Debian with ISPConfig and it seems that I need a Windows Server. I that possible to add Office365 authentication on a Linux server ?
- I have an Azure AD and would like the Office365 login to be the mail of my users. I think this is what they call Synchronized identity but I didn't find any resources on how to do this.
- Yesterday while trying the plugin [SSO-AAD-Wordpress](https://github.com/psignoret/aad-sso-wordpress) I had the button to login using Azure but when connecting I had "Sorry, but we're having trouble signing you in". I don't know why.

Thank you for your help :)

EDIT : It works now but I have to manually add the users to the Wordpress database. The other thing is that it works with Azure, not with Office365 (I don't know if it's worst mentioning).

Comment: What was the error with the last one? And have you registered your website in Azure AD?

Comment: To make your app accessible from any Azure AD, including other Office 365 tenants, you have to make the app *multi-tenant*. Read more [here](http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/azure-ad-what%E2%80%99s-the-difference-between-single-vs-multi-tenant). But as for why they must be manually added in WP, I really don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Azure AD authentication works for the most part with browser redirects. The OS doesn't matter.
2. If you want the users' login name to be like first.last@company.com, you will have to register that domain in your Azure AD and set it up as the default.
3. For the last one we can't really help you unless you tell more details.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. The error when I was logging was "Sorry, but we're having trouble signing you in", and it didn't redirect to my Wordpress. For Azure AD, yes I have registered the app but I was wondering if I have to do it on Azure portal or Office Portal ?

Comment: I think both will still do it the same in the end. But the Azure Portal is probably the best place. Is that all the error said? Usually at the bottom there are some more details.

Comment: Ok great. I have a new error which is less scary : "The authenticated user ttttttt@example.com is not a registered user in this blog."

Comment: Add that to your question. Sorry to say I don't really know much about WordPress, even less about that plug-in :/

Comment: Thanks Juunas, I'll add it. Actually it works now but I have to manually add the users to my wordpress to enable Azure sign-in.